# How do I change the name of Syntax in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using a package for sublime named the "C++ Starting Kit", and it has an enhanced syntax specifically for C and C++.  It seems that I can't set this as my default syntax for C or C++ as sublime keeps changing the default back to the default syntax.  From testing a bit, it seems that this problem is caused by the names of the starter-kit's syntax being the same as the default syntax, so I am trying to find a way to change the starter-kit's syntax name to be something like "C++ST".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to install [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) to access the files stored in the zipped `.sublime-package` file. Once installed, open the Command Palette and select `PackageResourceViewer: Extract Package` and select `C++ Starting Kit` from the dropdown. Next, select **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** to open Sublime's `Packages` directory in your operating system's file manager:

- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`
- OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`
- Windows Regular Install: `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages`
- Windows Portable Install: `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages`

Go to the `C++ Starting Kit` directory and open the `C.tmLanguage` and `C++.tmLanguage` files in Sublime with XML syntax. Near the top, look for the following:

```xml
<key>name</key>
<string>C</string>
```

or

```xml
<key>name</key>
<string>C++</string>
```

Change the `<string>` values to `C ST` and `C++ ST`, respectively, then save the files and close them. Next, in your file manager, rename `C.tmLanguage` to `C ST.tmLanguage` and `C.sublime-settings` to `C ST.sublime-settings`, and do the same for the C++ `.tmLanguage` and `.sublime-settings` files as well.

The changes should take effect immediately, but if not you can restart Sublime.